# Why is the point returning a NaN and Undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm running a discord bot and using a mongoDB database to talk to it.

```
async function checkPoint(arrayPoint, collection){
    const trial = await collection.findOne({ [arrayPoint]: { $exists: true }})
    if(trial == null){
        console.log("Player didn't exist, ergo we make a new area for them, for our good player buddy " + arrayPoint)
        tempObj = "1";
        collection.insertOne({ [arrayPoint]: tempObj}, {arrayPoint} )
    }else if(trial != null){
        console.log("It seems we have data ! Aha !" + arrayPoint )
        console.log(trial.arrayPoint)
        value = parseInt(trial.arrayPoint);
        console.log(value)
        value = value + 1;
        value = value.toString();
        console.log(value)
        collection.updateOne({name: {arrayPoint}}, {$set: {value}})
    }
}
```

Instead of returning proper values, it returns

> undefined
> NaN
> NaN

Trial itself is

```
{
  '96773755035992064': '1'
}
```

any help would be appreciated
I've tried everything in the documentation, and I don't really know what to do?

Comment: What "returns"? Nothing of you code actually returns anything. You have a few `console.log` which I assume log `undefined` and 2 times `NaN` ? Do a `console.log(trial)` to see how the `trial` object looks like. It probably doesn't have a `arrayPoint` property (thus the first log of `undefined`). Then you are trying to `parseInt(trial.arrayPoint)` which returns `NaN` (because the parameter is `undefined`) and then you are calculating `NaN + 1` which also gives `NaN` ...

Comment: What you probably want to do, is if `arrayPoint == '96773755035992064'` you want to access `trial['96773755035992064']`? Then the correct syntax is `value = parseInt(trial[arrayPoint])`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: sorry how do i add more info?

Comment: `
    exports.updatePlayerFunctions = (array) =>{
        arrayLength = array.length - 1;
        const colecter = userdb.collection("Points");
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            checkPoint(array[i], colecter)
        }
    }
`
this code is used to enter a string which IS a field name in a mongodb log. Trial isn't an array, its a mongodb datapoint.,

Comment: Your current code is literally accessing a property named `arrayPoint`, ie `{ arrayPoint: "1"}` Does your mongodb document have a field named `arrayPoint`? Judging from your output, it does not ... And also juding from the way you insert it as `{[arrayPoint]: ...}` the parameter arrayPoint you are passing to your `checkPoint` function carries the name of the field, you want to access. So accessing `trial.arrayPoint` is wrong, and `trial[arrayPoint]` is the way to go ...